# Excel 2007-style folder browse dialog

Tags: c#, winapi, excel-2007

Excel 2007 uses an updated/custom version of the standard Windows folder browse dialog, which you can see if you navigate to Office Button -> Excel Options -> Save -> Server drafts location -> Browse...

Our client wants us to use that dialog instead of the standard C# `FolderBrowserDialog` - is this possible (i.e. what Win32 DLLs/API calls would need to be made), and more to the point, would it be legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application.FileDialog object should give you what you're looking for. You can customise it to allow multi-select, set the initial folder, set a file type filter, etc. No API calls required

[MSDN FileDialog Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432103.aspx)

[MSDN FileDialog Object Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433413.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 (possibly vista) you might be able to find the code in here.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

I've noticed they finally got rid of the old folder browser in 7 with a new one that looks like an open file dialog, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but a +1 for the useful link.